# Let $f: [0, 1] \to [0, 1] $ be continuous. Show that there is a point $x$ such that $f(x) =x$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

> Let $f: [0, 1] \to [0, 1] $ be continuous. Show that there is a point $x$ such that $f(x) =x$

Now the standard argument that one uses for a proof for this is to define $g(x) = f(x) - x$ and then use the Intermediate Value Theorem, but what happens in the case that $f(1) = 0$, then $g(1) = -1 \not\in [0, 1]$, how does one prove $g(x)$ is a well defined function, given that we have no idea how $f(x)$ is defined?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot make the argument working with $g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2):

The function $g$ can have arbitrary codomain because the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) is right for every function $g:I \subset \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$.

The main thing to notice here is that $g(1)=f(1)-1 \leq 0$ and $g(0)=f(0) \geq 0$ since the values of $f$ are in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $g(x)=f(x)-x :[0,1]\rightarrow [-2,2] $is a
continuous function. We have the following cases:

1) If $g(1)=0$, then $f(1)=1$.

2) If  $g(0)=0$, then $f(0)=0$.

3) If   $g(0)\neq 0$ and  $g(0)\neq 0$, then, by definition of
$g$, we have $g(1)< 0$ and $g(0)> 0$. Thus by intermediate theorem
there exists $x\in [0, 1]$ with $g(x)=0$, and so $f (x)=x $. which proves the
result.

Comment: What's $h$ here?